# Notepad++ regex highlighting

Tags: notepad++, regex, highlighting

I'd like to be able to highlight entire lines in notepad++ by keywords, but these keywords would be added in the end of each line.

I tried with the available mechanism of "User Defined Language" styling but there is no chance of using regular expressions to match those lines.

So the question would be how to achieve this with the available options in Notepad++ or with a 3rd party plugin.

Example of line is needed to highlight:

- Task about doing something for someone => DONE

I would need the whole line to be highlighted permanently (as long as the style is applied to the document) according to the keyword "DONE".
I would also like the solution to be capable of highlight styles for different keywords (IN_PROGRESS, CANCELLED, etc)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I came here for searching how to improve the code highlighting. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Came here by coincidence, just want to add this custom python script solution: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/13183/poorman-regex-based-styler-lexer/16

Answer (score -1):

I cannot help you with highlighting different lines in different colors at the same time, but finding those lines is, in fact, very easy. Open the find window, select at the bottom "Regular expressions" and type into the search field `^.*keyword`. Replace `keyword` with the word you need found. Then press find next, or find all to highlight all the occurences. It will select the whole line, as long as the keyword is at the end. If not, if will select everything from the beginning of the line up to the keyword, including.

Explanation:

- `^` Start at the beginning of the line,
- `.` match any character...
- `*` ... any number of times,
- until you reach `keyword`.

If there is no `keyword` on that line, it will be skipped.

Comment: I appreciate the idea @KardNails, but it is not what I am looking for